# Not able to check any checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am not able check any checkbox in my web app based on jquery. I have tried to commenting out the event.preventDefaults. But still no improvement. What could prevent the checkboxes to be being checked.

Any guess friends!

Thanks.

Comment: @Pekka: If its happening just in some places i could post that parts code. But its happening all over the application. Its a single page app. We have less than 50 checkboxes here and there in the app. I am not able to check any of them. Something is preventing them to be checked. First i thought, it may be the `e.preventDefault's & return false` i have fixed them all. Still the issue persists!!

Comment: javascript error on other spot may cause that problem

Comment: If you look at the web app in FireFox with the Firebug add-on or in Google Chrome with the inspector window open, you will see if any Javascript errors are occurring. If so, post them here with your code.

Comment: Is there a live example we can look at?

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you want to check all the checkboxes at one go.

```
$('input[@type=checkbox]').attr('checked','checked');
```